# Need to get the uploaded file to my local PC

Tags: python, file, upload, file-upload

I have created a test form which will ask users to enter a name and upload the image file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Testing image upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/services/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File Description: <input name='fdesc' type='text'><br>
    File name: <input type="file" name="fname"><br>
    <div><input type="submit"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i need to get the file uploaded by the user and store it on my local PC. can this be done in python ? please let me know.

Comment: sorry for an error, my local PC means our development server itself on which the above mentioned html file is loaded. is it possible to get the file and store it in /tmp or some other location.

Comment: How are you using Python? mod_python, mod_wsgi, a CGI script, or something else?

Comment: its and apache server and i am using mod_python

Answer (score 1):

mod_python includes the [`FieldStorage` class](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pyapi-util-fstor.html) which allows you access to uploaded form data. In order to use it, you'd put something like the following in your Python script:

```
req.form = FieldStorage(req)
description = req.form['fdesc']
```

Since `fdesc` is a text input, `description` will be a string (more precisely, a `StringField`, which you can treat as a string).

```
file_field = req.form['fname']
```

Since `fname` is a file input, `file_field` will not be a string (or `StringField`), but rather a [`Field`](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pyapi-util-fstor-fld.html) object which allows you access to the file data. The attribute `file_field.file` is a file-like object which you can use to read the file's contents, for example like so:

```
for line in file_field.file:
    # process the line
```

You could use this to copy the file's data somewhere of your choosing, for example.

`file_field.filename` is the name of the file as provided by the client. Other useful attributes are listed in the documentation I linked to.

Comment: David, I am not able to get it working, i think i am doing it wrong way, can you give me some example.

Comment: I did. There are a few lines of example code in my answer and there are more complete examples at the links I gave you. If you've gone through those and haven't been able to figure out why your code isn't working, post a new question (since "why doesn't this work" is a separate question from "how do I do it"), and make sure to include your code and the details of your error message.

Answer (score 0):

Maybie the [minimal http cgi upload recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/273844-minimal-http-upload-cgi/) and it's comments are helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey David i got it working, i did it this way:

```
filename = request.FILES['fname']
destination = open('%s/%s'%(/tmp/,fileName), 'wb+')
for chunk in filename.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
destination.close()

file = open('%s/%s'%(/tmp/,fileName),"rb").read()
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: It's fine to post your code as an answer if nobody else's answer is sufficient, but you probably shouldn't write it as if you're responding to someone else.